# Data recovery from partially working external hard disk, which makes clicking and screeching sound intermittently

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

Following is disk part command info for external hard disk which shows only drive letter in Windows 10, and no access to (1.1 GB of) files or folders in it.

Disk part output:

```
Samsung M3 Portable USB Device
Disk ID: 66742A00
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 6     E                RAW    Partition   1863 GB  Healthy
```

Till morning it was working fine, with very mild hiss and screeching sound, but suddenly in afternoon it was inaccessible. After opening case actuator head was found to be in good condition while running it.

Data recovery software's recover some files, but fails to recover data fully, as probably disk becomes inaccessible after some time, or windows displays following message at regular intervals;

```
You need to format the disk in drive E:\ before you can use it.
```

Are there any options, hardware or software tools, by which data can be recovered without sending it to special labs?

**Note:** LED light blinks, and disk spins, in any case.

Comment: Are you serious?  You opened the drive?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, had to do that, just to check whether head was stuck or not. Took care while opening drive, so no damage from that step (afaik). For further actions, was considering to visit professional, due to lack of tools, and info. But first need to make sure, that it would be the only last step.

Answer (score 2):

Opening the drive was *literally the absolute **WORST** thing you could have done*.  If any dust has gotten onto the platters or the head it can destroy the data on the disk.  Not to mention just spinning the drive up now can cause the head to crash into the platters.

I genuinely dont know what you thought you were going to accomplish by doing this.  If the actuator arm was stuck, or even if it wasnt, what were you going to do?

If the data is important, then send it to a professional data recovery place.  If you havent already done permanent damage, they *might* be able to recover some data.  However, at this point I wouldnt hold my breath.

For future reference, ***NEVER*** open a hard disk drive unless you are a qualified professional in a clean room.  There are no user serviceable parts in a drive.